# Cancel/Abort/Confirm an HTML 5 state change event (onpopstate)

Tags: javascript, html

With unload event of window, it is possible to show the user a confirmation dialog , let's say in a situation where there is an ongoing request you are waiting for to finish and navigating away from the page will terminate that request.

Is there a way to accomplish this with onpopstate of HTML5 history API? Or any other way with the same outcome?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could modify the behavior of pushState to ask for confirmation before pushing a new state :

```
// Store original pushState
var _pushState = window.history.pushState;
// Some bad global variable to determine if confirmation is needed
var askForConfirm = true;
// Modify pushState behavior
window.history.pushState = function() {
    if(!askForConfirm || confirm('Are you sure you want to quit this page ?')) {
        // Call original pushState
        _pushState.apply(window.history,arguments);
    }
};
```

Comment: But this doesn't take care of situations where the user has causes the event to fire (e.g. by pressing the back button)

Comment: Hm. Well, then maybe it's possible to handle this on the onpopstate event, by storing the previous state and pushing it back in case of cancel... Seems a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps in your situation, but Sammy.js, a popular hash-routing library has a [before](http://sammyjs.org/docs/api/0.7.4/all#Sammy.Application-before) handler. I've used it in my application to record the previously accessed hash, and if it's the hash I want to stop them from leaving, return false will keep them on that page. You still need to rewrite the URL to display the previous page, but it seems to be working.

See [my answer in this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096083/152648) for more info.